# Double array with symbol generator C++

Tags: c++

everyone I am trying to make a program that creates a double array 6x5 and fills it with symbols by generator. Then I have to find the symbol with the smallest number and print it on the screen. So far this is what I've made, but I am struggling with the rest of the code.

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,j,n,m;

    char a[6][5];
    cout<<"rows: ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"columns: ";
    cin>>m;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            a[i] [j]=(char)rand()%128;
        }
    }           

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody help me with code to make the program find the lowest symbol number and prints it?

Comment: Please, indent your code. And if you want us to read and understand what you're doing, use English

Comment: sorry, I forgot to change the language... just fixed it

Comment: It's a general algorythm, you should try to learn algorythms and pseudocode first and then complex languages. Anyway, hint: `if (array[i][j] < smallest) smallest = array[i][j];`

Comment: i apologize but i do not understand what you mean by "symbols by generator" and especially what is a "symbol with smallest number".  please clarify.

Comment: symbols entered in the array by a generator of random ASCII symbols, and I am looking for the symbol with the lowest ASCI code (number)

Comment: Indenting incorrectly is far worse than not indenting at all, as it makes the code confusing. Take a look  at the placement of `{` and `}`, including one hidden at the end of line.

Comment: Here's another hint: Printable, non-whitespace ASCII starts at 33 and ends at 126. As written, `cout << a[i][j] << " ";` is likely to send control characters such as the BELL (ASCII 7), backspace (ASCII 8), etc. to `cout`, leading to unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate through all your element and store invariable value (and possibly position) of the smallest element found so far.

```
char min_value = CHAR_MAX;
int min_i = 0, min_j = 0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        if ( a[i][j] < min_value )
        {
            min_i = i;
            min_j = j;
            min_value = a[i][j];
        }
    }
}

std::cout << "Found smallest at a[" << min_i << "][" << min_j << ": " << (int)min_value << std::endl;
```

By the way, why are you asking user for `m` and `n` when you actually know you want a 6x5 array? And what happens if `n>6` or `m>5`? Your code will fill the array out of bounds....